# Cookie in Thunder Client VS Code extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, cookies

I am working on an API and Thunder client extension in VS code seems to have change the way of sending cookies along on every request. How do I do that, any help will be appreciated.

**Cookie is not sent along with request:**
I have a REST API, when I log-in I get an accessToken and a cookie, but I need to pass the cookie along on every request to refresh endpoint to get a refreshToken.

The cookie is not showing in Thunder Client.

Watching [this Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2EqECiTBL8&t=18366s)

**To Reproduce:**
Try to send a cookie to refresh endpoint to get a new refreshToken

**Expected Behavior:**
The cookie is supposed to be automatically sent along on every request to the refresh endpoint

**What I tried:**
I get this error after following [the docs](https://github.com/rangav/thunder-client-support#setenv)

```js
Set Env Failed: Unable to parse left input query - cookie.jwt
```

[image: code]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would have to set cookie secure option to "false" when generating your refresh Token. (see below):

[image: secure is set to false]

Thunder client extension in VS code does not recognise localhost development server urls as protected routes (https or http secure) (for example http://localhost:3500/refresh and http://localhost:3500/auth), hence it will not make the token available for requests. So the only option is to set the secure option to "false" to allow it to pass.

There may be a way to tweak this in the settings or stuff but i have not figured that out, but the good thing is that in production you will be fine with secure option set as true, as the server domain will be recognised as https or http secure.

Comment: fixed my problem, thaks.

Comment: I'd add that it could be useful to have a constant defined in some constants.js file that checks and stores if the current execution environment is Prod or Dev. Something like __prod__ = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production". You could then set the secure attribute to __prod__

Comment: @Musilix that's a good one too.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit off-topic, but I wound up on this question when I tried to troubleshoot my issue.
My API request stopped reusing cookies set from a request opened in another tab (weird).
This question gave me a hint to take a look at the Cookie Manager - it turned out, it started saving cookies under the `127.0.0.1` domain instead of the `localhost` (there were outdated cookies under the `localhost` domain, which is why I think it was working before that way).
Solution - in your GET/POST/DELETE/etc HTTP request within the ThunderClient user interface, set the target URL from
`http://localhost:port/uri` to `http://127.0.0.1:port/uri`.
Might save someone time, if they will have a similar case.